# Reference request on the stochastic heat equation.

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I was watching a [lecture of fields medalist Martin Hairer](https://youtu.be/4N70I5_Ervk?t=4m52s) where he briefly describes a construction of a discrete model where the stochastic heat equation 
arises. (the youtube link starts with the construction).

Where could I read more on this construction? I haven't done it in the standard courses.

Comment: you can find reference for this in notes containing Fokker Plank equations and Brownian motion, since the heat equations are the FPE for the BM. It's very standard theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation

Comment: @Diesirae92, the OP is interested in the stochastic heat equation, which is the heat equation with an additive noise term.  It is a stochastic PDE (i.e. the solution of the PDE is a stochastic process in an infinite dimensional space).  This isn't actually "standard" stuff at all.